# Install RPM with Puppet and execute script

Tags: puppet, rpm

I have an RPM that installs a shell script. Puppet code needs to access this RPM, retrieve the shell script packaged in the RPM and execute it. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract rpm scriptlets by

```
rpm -qp --script foo.rpm
```

Just beware that it contains ALL scripts (%pre, %post, %postun...) so you need to use sed or something similar to extract just that one script, save it to file and the run.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a package statement to install the rpm, and then an exec to run the shell script.  Assuming your rpm is called my-shellscript.rpm, and is located in your module's files directory, and the rpm defines the install location as /tmp/my-shellscript.sh, then you'll have something like this,

```
class example {    

    package { 'my-shellscript.rpm' :
        ensure   => 'installed',
        provider => 'rpm',
        source   => 'puppet:///modules/example/my-shellscript.rpm',
    }

    exec { 'my-shellscript.sh':
        command => '/tmp/my-schellscript.sh', 
        require => Package['my-shellscript.rpm'],
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute the script from your code, you need to perform the following steps :

1. Extract the contents of your rpm in some temporary directory.You can use rpmcpio utility for that.

   `rpm2cpio test.rpm |cpio -idmv`
2. Find the location of script in your rpm file. you can use rpm command for that.

   `rpm -qpl test.rpm |grep "script.sh"`
3. In your code, execute the script from the temporary location where you had extracted your rpm contents.

   `sh /tmp/test/xxx/script.sh`